# What is the advantage of using prototype in combination with new?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

From a book I got this example of inheritance:

```
var Animal = function(){};
Animal.prototype.sleep = function(){
    // ...
};

var Cat = function(){};
// Cat is an animal
Cat.prototype = new Animal;
Cat.prototype.meow = function(){
    // ...
};

var scratchy = new Cat();
scratchy.sleep();
scratchy.meow();
```

But this also works and seems to be more intuitive to me. Why don't you do it? Or do you? Does it create a reference instead of copying the prototype properties?

```
Cat.prototype = Animal.prototype;
```

Comment: [This might help](http://js-bits.blogspot.co.uk/2010/08/constructors-without-using-new.html).

Comment: I have tried to create the most complete JavaScript prototype, (multiple) inheritance, overriding, using Super and the `this` value answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941 Hope it helps and if you have any questions please feel free to ask them so I can improve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do `Cat.prototype = Animal.prototype;` and then try to add to `Cat.prototype`, you are also adding to `Animal.prototype`. The current best practice is actually

```
Cat.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. This means that any change to `Cat.prototype` will be reflected to `Animal`, i.e. subclass mehods appearing in the superclass!
2. Any `Animal` member defined in the constructor, will not be available when doing `new Cat()`. E.g. suppose the `Animal` constructor was:

   ```
   function Animal(birthDate) {
       this.birthDate = birthDate;
   }
   ```

   The `Cat` of the former method will contain the `birthDate` property, the second method's `Cat` will not.

Comment: For your point `2`, doing `Cat.prototype = new Animal();` will still result in an _undefined_ (but initialised) `birthDate`, and all cats will be recorded as born on the same date. If it is really necessary for the constructor to be invoked, it may be better done with `inheritConstructor.call(this);`

Comment: Yes, you are right. The second point has only marginal validity.

Answer (score 0):

In the previous code with `Cat.prototype = new Animal` you are invoking the Animal constructor function `var Animal = function() {};` which is going to create a new object, run that constructor function and any code within it, assign `this` to the new object, the prototype property is attached to the constructor function, and return the new object. The use of `new` looks familiar to how you make a 'class' with classical inheritance but **Javascript** uses **PROTOTYPAL Inheritence** to make new objects that inherit from other objects.

By doing `Cat.protoype = Animal.prototype` you are not doing what was previously mentioned you are assigning the prototypes to each other so if you add something to one it will affect the other.